# How do I accurately count a set of entities in App Engine, when 30 million already exist?

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I have a collection of ~30 million entities at the moment, and I'd like to accurately count them. I know that I need a sharded counter that +1's every time a new entity is written (current write rate is around 1.5 per sec). The difficult bit is how do I count the existing entities, without preventing new writes?

I can happily write a map reduce job to do the counting, but I want to ensure that:

1. Existing and future writes aren't counted twice
2. The map reduce only counts everything up to a point, and the new process that runs on every write only counts everything that isn't already counted by the map reduce job.

I'm happy with a small margin of error, but want to minimise it as much as possible.

If it helps, there is a write date on each of these properties, but I'd like to extend the counting to cover other entities too, which do not have this date field.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Why do you need an exact count of entities? Can you work around it? What about using the datastore stats interface - is that data good enough?

Comment: @NickJohnson In general, is it possible to ever achieve an exact count on a large, distributed system like App Engine?  To my mind, there will always be failure modes beyond the programmer's control which prevent such a guarantee.

Comment: @mvanveen Not in general, no - because your data is distributed across many machines, there's no way to get a count from all of them and guarantee it's still accurate by the time you return it.

Comment: @nickjohnson to be honest, I don't need it - this certainly isn't a matter of life or death! But I am curious if it was possible.

Comment: @nickjohnson just as a thought - have you got any details on how regularly and how accurate the datastore stats are? I'm thinking about a bit of a mash up solution of all the answers and comments so far: using the stats interface as a starting point and then doing a sharded counter for every entity added after that. The question is whether to reset my counter every time the App Engine stats are updated and how I might listen for that. It also depends on whether the stats are written as soon as counting finishes or if there is a significant time delay? Thanks!

Comment: @edhgoose They're updated once a day. I'm still curious why you need this - sharded counters are a lot of effort to put in, and add a lot of complication to your system.

Comment: @nickjohnson I want to show a live count of how many entities are collected. I'm curious as to why it's difficult? I've used the sharded counter sample code before on another project and it was pretty simple. Am I missing something?

Comment: @edhgoose It's not difficult in theory, but there are practical issues. How many shards you need depends on how much traffic you get; it's difficult to adjust shards randomly. Keeping a live count adds latency to every request, and the whole thing adds complication to the system. If it only needs to be mostly accurate, may I suggest [write-behind counters](http://blog.notdot.net/2010/04/High-concurrency-counters-without-sharding)?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9536/discussion-between-edhgoose-and-nick-johnson)

Answer (score 2):

Just mark the "new" entities in some way: timestamp, boolean field, etc.. And then exclude them from the query that you use for counting "existing" entities.

Comment: And if it isn't already clear from this answer: start the new sharded counter *before* you run the job to count things that were created before it started.

Comment: I'm not sure this will work by itself.  Or at least, as described without some more nuance, this seems dangerous.  Say that your `put` fails in the middle of updating your object.  You have updated your counter object, but for some reason you haven't successfully updated the object with your timestamp/boolean/whatever.  Your now going to force a double count.  The opposite case works against you too, causing you to count less than the total # of objects.

Comment: @mvanveen: updating what object? It's only newly-created entities that are going to be marked, nothing is updated. And the questioner claims to know how to do the sharded counter -- even if that's false I think it's reasonable for answers to leave that to the questioner.

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun: Create a count entity. Update it via pull queue once every N seconds (N > 1). As new records come in, send a count task to the pull queue. Current count is entity value plus the task queue "stats.totalTasks". Use a memcache variable to handle the brief "work in process count" for the time when pull queue is processing leased tasks so as to update the entity count (not sure if they might be double counted). Too much overhead for this of course, but wanted to throw it out there to highlight a task queue approach. (I do something like this to maintain certain usage stats -- but these don't need to real-time.) hth -stevep relevant doc link is below, plus there is a fantastic Google video on pull queues (link s/b easy to find):
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/rest

Answer (score 0):

Could you simply have a task that goes through all the entities adding the keys to a second table if they don't already exist. This can be run multiple times before switchover time X.

Modify the insertion of entities to also add their key to this table if the current time is before X, and if time is > X then increment your counter.

Once the switchover has happened, and the counter is being incremented by the new insertions you know that all entities before X are in the key table, and the rest are counter. Just simply go through the key table incrementing the counter and removing the key.